# How to replace "%" inside vim? \% doesn't work

Tags: vim, text, replace, percentage

I have c format text like this:

```
"%d %d"
```

I wish to change it into text like "%l %l"

I tried in vim command mode like:

```
:%s:\%d:\%l:g
```

It doesn't work. Then I tried:

```
:%s:%%d:%%l:g
```

Doesn't work either. How to fix it?

Comment: `:%s:%d:%l:g` works, at least for neovim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape the `%` character. Either of these work:

```
:%s/%d/%l/g
:%s:%d:%l:g
```

You're not limited to just `/` or `:` as delineation characters though. From vim's help:

> Instead of the '/' which surrounds the pattern and replacement string, you
>   can use any other single-byte character, but not an alphanumeric character,
>   '\', '"' or '|'.  This is useful if you want to include a '/' in the search
>   pattern or replacement string.  Example: >
>       :s+/+//+

Comment: Where can you see that OP used `/` as delimiter ??

Comment: Op already knows that as he is using `:` instead of `/` the default one.